# Converting into range in Python

Tags: list, python-2.6

I want to convert a list into range.

```
a = ['Eth1/1', 'Eth1/2', 'Eth1/3', 'Eth1/4', 'Eth1/5', 'Eth1/6', 'Eth1/7', 'Eth1/8', 'Eth1/9', 'Eth1/10','Eth2/1', 'Eth2/2', 'Eth2/3', 'Eth2/4', 'Eth2/5', 'Eth2/6','Eth3/1', 'Eth3/2', 'Eth3/3', 'Eth3/4', 'Eth3/5', 'Eth3/6','Eth4/1', 'Eth4/2', 'Eth4/3', 'Eth4/4', 'Eth4/5', 'Eth4/6']
```

what i am trying :

```
fp = open('mode.txt' , 'w+')
for i in a:           
            fp.write('confi ' + i + '\n mode \n')
```

what i am looking for :

```
confi Eth1/1-5
  mode
confi Eth1/6-10
  mode
confi Eth2/1-6
  mode
confi Eth3/1-6
  mode
confi Eth4/1-6
  mode
```

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: So, why does the range divided in 1-5 and 6-10? Any criteria for that?

Comment: @Andreas looking for group of 5

Comment: Let 'a" be like that ..

Comment: @Andreas i updaed the question ..can we get the output i mentioned ? Logic :divide line in chunk of 5 where Eth1 exist and for line consist Eth2 , take everything ?

Comment: @Andreas what if i have to do thing for Eth3  same to what we do for Eth2..

Comment: @Andreas update the question ..Basically we ant to divide Eth1 in group of 5 and For rest of Eth like Eth2, Eth3,Eth4 ,take everything

Comment: Updated my answer. Also, please include `Basically we want to divide Eth1 in group of 5 and For rest of Eth like Eth2, Eth3,Eth4 ,take everything` in your question too.

Comment: can we remove the downward space in output ?

Comment: @Andreas e;g there is space between "mode " and "confi Eth1/6-10" and then between "mode" and "confi Eth2/1-6"and so on...Can we delete that space ?

Comment: hey , dont see any difference , what was updated ?

Comment: removed the space after mode in the print statement (`...mode\n` instead of `...mode \n`)

Comment: No luck ... i still see space...

Comment: @Andreas hey , could you please help me in arranging   a = ['Eth1/1', 'Eth1/48','Eth2/1', 'Eth2/4','Eth101/1/1', 'Eth101/1/2', 'Eth101/1/3','Eth102/1/1', 'Eth102/1/2', 'Eth102/1/3','Eth103/1/1', 'Eth103/1/2', 'Eth103/1/3','Eth103/1/4','Eth104/1/1', 'Eth104/1/2', 'Eth104/1/3','Eth104/1/4']

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Please try to infer that from my answer instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a loop that checks the current element as the `start`. If it starts with `Eth1` then get the 4th element after as the `end`. Otherwise, keep the starting `Eth_`, iterate through the list until you get the last `Eth_` element or until the list end. Assign the last element as the `end`.

```
a = ['Eth1/1', 'Eth1/2', 'Eth1/3', 'Eth1/4', 'Eth1/5', 'Eth1/6', 'Eth1/7', 'Eth1/8', 'Eth1/9', 'Eth1/10','Eth2/1', 'Eth2/2', 'Eth2/3', 'Eth2/4', 'Eth2/5', 'Eth2/6','Eth3/1', 'Eth3/2', 'Eth3/3', 'Eth3/4', 'Eth3/5', 'Eth3/6','Eth4/1', 'Eth4/2', 'Eth4/3', 'Eth4/4', 'Eth4/5', 'Eth4/6']
i = 0

while i < len(a):
    start = a[i].split('/')
    if (start[0] == 'Eth1'):
        i += 5
    else:
        key = start[0]
        i += 1
        while i < len(a) and a[i].split('/')[0] == key:
            i += 1
    end = a[i-1].split('/')
    print('confi ' + start[0] + '/' + start[1] + '-' + end[1] + '\n mode\n')
```